# Evaluating list of boolean methods ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a list of methods who if any of them evaluated to true, I have to trigger an action on the model, in this case it's model audit.

So for example :

```
def a?
  false # in reality this is some code
end

def b?
  true # in reality this is some code
end

def c?
  true # in reality this is some code
end
```

Now I can group this into like a parent method like :

```
def parent_method
  a? || b? || c?
end
```

This will short-circuit the code, and c? will never be executed which is great. I can execute my `.audit` method.

But if I wanted to pass in custom message to my `.audit` method, and I wanted to have different message for every method how can I do that?

My first though to have a hash with keys being the methods and values being the messages or something along that line. But in that case the short circuiting doesn't work as all methods are evaluated in advance. How can I make this work better and more efficient/elegant?

Comment: You could follow a similar patters as [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).  In this case , the individual validation methods add a message to an `errors` object.  The `valid?` method simply checks if any error messages have been recorded. You could have your `a?`, `b?` and `c?` methods populate an array and then your `parent_method` inspects the array to determine if the audit passes or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `true` your method could return a *trueish* value like a symbol.

```
def a?
  false # in reality this is some code
end

def b?
  :b # in reality this is some code
end

def c?
  :c # in reality this is some code
end
```

That you still allow to short-circuit the code in

```
def parent_method
  a? || b? || c?
end
```

But now `parent_method` will not only return `true` or `false` but it would return a symbol that your allow returning a message that might be stored in a hash:

```
key = parent_method
audit(key) if key
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always break these out into a simple array if you're not passing in any arguments. A minimal example looks like:

```
TESTS = [ :a?, :b?, :c? ]

def parent_method
  failed = TESTS.find do |test|
    !send(test)
  end

  if (failed)
    # The failed variable contains the name of the method that failed
    # to return `true`. Do whatever you need to do here.
    errors << "Test #{failed} returned false!"

    false
  else
    true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> if I wanted to pass in custom message to my `.audit` method, and I wanted to have different message for every method how can I do that?

You could use a [`case` expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression):

```
case
when a? then audit(:a)
when b? then audit(:b)
when c? then audit(:c)
end
```